tf2 Quaternion doesn't work as expected
I'm trying to reproduce ros2 Humble documentation tf2::Quaternion Rotations example, but results doesn't match. Sample code:
#include <tf2/LinearMath/Matrix3x3.h>
#include <tf2/LinearMath/Quaternion.h>
#include <tf2/LinearMath/Transform.h>

tf2::Vector3 rosEuler(0, M_PI_2, M_PI_2);
tf2::Quaternion rosQuat;
rosQuat.setRPY(rosEuler.x(), rosEuler.y(), rosEuler.z());
std::cout << "\nROS - Roll: " << rosEuler.x() << ", Pitch: "<< rosEuler.y() <<", Yaw: " << rosEuler.z() << std::endl << std::endl;

tf2::Vector3 rosToOpticalEuler(-M_PI_2, 0, -M_PI_2);
tf2::Quaternion rosToOpticalQuat;
rosToOpticalQuat.setRPY(rosToOpticalEuler.x(), rosToOpticalEuler.y(), rosToOpticalEuler.z());
std::cout << "ROS_TO_OPTICAL - Roll: " << rosToOpticalEuler.x() << ", Pitch: "<< rosToOpticalEuler.y() <<", Yaw: " << rosToOpticalEuler.z() << std::endl << std::endl;

auto opticalQuat = rosToOpticalQuat * rosQuat;
opticalQuat.normalize();
tf2::Matrix3x3 mat(opticalQuat);
double roll, pitch, yaw;
mat.getRPY(roll, pitch, yaw);
auto opticalEuler = tf2::Vector3(roll, pitch, yaw);
std::cout << "Optical - Roll: " << opticalEuler.x() << ", Pitch: " << opticalEuler.y() << ", Yaw: " << opticalEuler.z() << std::endl << std::endl;

auto restoredRosQuat = rosToOpticalQuat.inverse() * opticalQuat;
restoredRosQuat.normalize();
tf2::Matrix3x3 mat2(restoredRosQuat);
double roll2, pitch2, yaw2;
mat2.getRPY(roll2, pitch2, yaw2);
auto restoredRosEuler = tf2::Vector3(roll2, pitch2, yaw2);
std::cout << "Restored Ros - Roll: " << restoredRosEuler.x() << ", Pitch: " << restoredRosEuler.y() << ", Yaw: " << restoredRosEuler.z() << std::endl << std::endl;

EXPECT_NEAR(rosEuler.x(), restoredRosEuler.x(), 1e-6);
EXPECT_NEAR(rosEuler.y(), restoredRosEuler.y(), 1e-6);
EXPECT_NEAR(rosEuler.z(), restoredRosEuler.z(), 1e-6);

Sample Output:
ROS            - Roll: 0,        Pitch: 1.5708,      Yaw: 1.5708
ROS_TO_OPTICAL - Roll: -1.5708,  Pitch: 0,           Yaw: -1.5708
Optical        - Roll: -3.14159, Pitch: 4.44089e-16, Yaw: -3.14159
Restored Ros   - Roll: 0.463648, Pitch: 1.5708,      Yaw: 1.5708

Why does not rosEuler.x() and restoredRosEuler.x() match?
I Also tried using tf2_ros::Buffer::transform() to archive same result, and not only ros and restored ros orientation doesn't match, but also optical orientation doesn't match with tf2::Quaternion multiplication results. Sample code:
rclcpp::init(0, nullptr);

auto node        = rclcpp::Node::make_shared("odom_test_node");
auto tfBuffer    = std::make_unique<tf2_ros::Buffer>(node->get_clock());
auto tfListener  = std::make_shared<tf2_ros::TransformListener>(*tfBuffer);
auto tfPub       = std::make_shared<tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster>(node);
auto staticTfPub = std::make_shared<tf2_ros::StaticTransformBroadcaster>(node);

tf2::Vector3 rosToOpticalEuler(-M_PI_2, 0, -M_PI_2);
//auto rosToOptical = RosTools::EulerToQuat(rosToOpticalEuler);
tf2::Quaternion rosToOptical;
rosToOptical.setRPY(rosToOpticalEuler.x(), rosToOpticalEuler.y(), rosToOpticalEuler.z());
std::cout << "\nROS_TO_OPTICAL - Roll: " << rosToOpticalEuler.x() << ", Pitch: "<< rosToOpticalEuler.y() <<", Yaw: " << rosToOpticalEuler.z() << std::endl << std::endl;

geometry_msgs::msg::Pose rosToOpticalPose;
tf2::convert(rosToOptical, rosToOpticalPose.orientation);
//RosTools::PublishTransform(nullptr, staticTfPub, node->now(), "front_camera_gyro_frame", "front_camera_gyro_optical_frame", rosToOpticalPose);
geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped msg;
msg.header.stamp = node->now();
msg.header.frame_id = "front_camera_gyro_frame";
msg.child_frame_id = "front_camera_gyro_optical_frame";
msg.transform.translation.x = rosToOpticalPose.position.x;
msg.transform.translation.y = rosToOpticalPose.position.y;
msg.transform.translation.z = rosToOpticalPose.position.z;
msg.transform.rotation = rosToOpticalPose.orientation;
staticTfPub->sendTransform(msg);
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));

tf2::Vector3 rosEuler(0, M_PI_2, M_PI_2);
//auto rosQuat = RosTools::EulerToQuat(rosEuler);
tf2::Quaternion rosQuat;
rosQuat.setRPY(rosEuler.x(), rosEuler.y(), rosEuler.z());
geometry_msgs::msg::Pose rosPose;
tf2::convert(rosQuat, rosPose.orientation);
std::cout << "ROS - Roll: " << rosEuler.x() << ", Pitch: "<< rosEuler.y() <<", Yaw: " << rosEuler.z() << std::endl << std::endl;

//auto opticalPose = RosTools::Transform(*tfBuffer, node->now(), rosPose, "front_camera_gyro_frame", "front_camera_gyro_optical_frame");
geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped rosPoseStamped;
rosPoseStamped.header.stamp = node->now();
rosPoseStamped.header.frame_id = "front_camera_gyro_frame";
rosPoseStamped.pose = rosPose;
geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped opticalPoseStamped;
try {
    tfBuffer->transform(
        rosPoseStamped, 
        opticalPoseStamped, 
        "front_camera_gyro_optical_frame",
        tf2::durationFromSec(0.05)
    );
} catch (const tf2::TransformException &ex) {
    std::cerr << "Could not transform <front_camera_gyro_frame> to <front_camera_gyro_optical_frame>: " << ex.what() << std::endl << std::flush;
    abort();
}
auto opticalPose = opticalPoseStamped.pose;

tf2::Quaternion opticalQuat;
tf2::convert(opticalPose.orientation, opticalQuat);
//auto opticalEuler = RosTools::QuatToEuler(opticalQuat);
tf2::Matrix3x3 mat(opticalQuat);
double roll, pitch, yaw;
mat.getRPY(roll, pitch, yaw);
auto opticalEuler = tf2::Vector3(roll, pitch, yaw);
std::cout << "Optical - Roll: " << opticalEuler.x() << ", Pitch: " << opticalEuler.y() << ", Yaw: " << opticalEuler.z() << std::endl << std::endl;

//auto restoredRosPose = RosTools::Transform(*tfBuffer, node->now(), opticalPose, "front_camera_gyro_optical_frame", "front_camera_gyro_frame");
geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped restoredRosPoseStamped;
try {
    tfBuffer->transform(
        opticalPoseStamped, 
        restoredRosPoseStamped, 
        "front_camera_gyro_frame",
        tf2::durationFromSec(0.05)
    );
} catch (const tf2::TransformException &ex) {
    std::cerr << "Could not transform <front_camera_gyro_optical_frame> to <front_camera_gyro_frame>: " << ex.what() << std::endl << std::flush;
    abort();
}
auto restoredRosPose = restoredRosPoseStamped.pose;

tf2::Quaternion restoredRosQuat;
tf2::convert(restoredRosPose.orientation, restoredRosQuat);
//auto restoredRosEuler = RosTools::QuatToEuler(restoredRosQuat);
tf2::Matrix3x3 mat2(restoredRosQuat);
double roll2, pitch2, yaw2;
mat2.getRPY(roll2, pitch2, yaw2);
auto restoredRosEuler = tf2::Vector3(roll2, pitch2, yaw2);
std::cout << "Restored Ros - Roll: " << restoredRosEuler.x() << ", Pitch: " << restoredRosEuler.y() << ", Yaw: " << restoredRosEuler.z() << std::endl << std::endl;

EXPECT_NEAR(rosEuler.x(), restoredRosEuler.x(), 1e-6);
EXPECT_NEAR(rosEuler.y(), restoredRosEuler.y(), 1e-6);
EXPECT_NEAR(rosEuler.z(), restoredRosEuler.z(), 1e-6);

rclcpp::shutdown();

Sample Output:
ROS_TO_OPTICAL - Roll: -1.5708, Pitch: 0,           Yaw: -1.5708
ROS            - Roll: 0,       Pitch: 1.5708,      Yaw: 1.5708
Optical        - Roll: -1.5708, Pitch: 2.22045e-16, Yaw: 1.5708
Restored Ros   - Roll: 0,       Pitch: 1.5708,      Yaw: 0

I tried to figure this out on my own, but it takes too much time... Maybe someone of the ROS2 experts can help me to understand what's going on...

The angle values you have chosen to test with are sitting very, very close to a singularity. This is not a problem for the quaternion representation, but it's sometimes a problem if you try to get the euler angles. Some math libraries handle this better than others.
